# How do I get Camera properties from a scene camera?

Tags: blender

In order to get the camera, I can use `bpy.data.objects["Camera"]`. This returns a Camera object corresponding to the camera named Camera.

However, when getting this camera from the scene, it does not get a Camera type but an Object type. `print(bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].camera)` returns `<bpy_struct, Object("Camera") at 0x14c170608>`.

I wish I could use this Object as a camera, but it does not provide the Camera properties I need.

Why is the camera I got from the scene an Object instead of a Camera, and how do I access the Camera properties I need from the scene?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the camera properties in `bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].camera.data`.